# Combine neighbouring elements in list

Tags: java, list

*I want to implement the [Newton interpolation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial#Example). Maybe that gives the following text more sense.*

I look for a List-Function that combines each two neighbors in a list to a new value. It should be pretty fast and (if possible) not involve creating new lists. I want to perform the reduction described below multiple times in a row, but grab some of the data in between.

```
Before: a   b   c   d
         \ / \ / \ /
After:    ab  bc  cd
```

The binary function by which it is combined should be freely switchable.

So far I came up with something like this (but for arrays):

```
double[] before = {4, 3, 7, 1};

while(before.length > 1){
    double[] after = new double[before.length - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < after.length; i++){
        after[i] = chosenBinaryFunction(before[i], before[i+1]);
    }

    //store after[0]

    before = after;
}
```

---

The answer "There is no better way than what you did" is acceptable. In that case please provide hints how to improve the method (for example avoid creating lots of new lists in the `while`, possible shortcuts, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely it's possible to avoid creating new arrays. The solution is quite simple as the left operand is not used anymore once it's used by for second computation so the algorithm can overwrite it:

```
double[] before = {4, 3, 7, 1};
int length = before.length;

while (length > 1) {
     --length;
     for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
         before[i] = chosenBinaryFunction(before[i], before[i+1]);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to be able to choose a binary function, look at [BinaryOperator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html). Specifically `BinaryOperator<double>`. Using this, add this line:

```
BinaryOperator<double> b = ...
```

Then you can change this line:

```
after[i] = chosenBinaryFunction(before[i], before[i+1]);
```

To this:

```
after[i] = bo.apply(before[i], before[i+1])
```

Also, I think it's wasteful that you create a new array every time you go through the loop. I would do something more like this (full version):

```
double newtonInterpolation(double[] before, BinaryOperator<double> bo) {
    double[] after = new double[before.length - 1] // Creates array ONE time

    for (int i = 0; i < after.length; i++) {
        after[i] = bo.apply(before[i], before[i + 1]) // Uses fancy BinaryOperator
    }

    return after
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this code yet, so it's provided "as-is", but I hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much got it for arrays.
The only thing is the condition of your for loop should be **i < after.length-1** or else, when the loop index (i) reaches the last position in your array, you will get IndexOutOfBounds exception, since you'll be calling the i+1 element in your array, that doesn't exist.

So for doing the above stuff with lists you start with a list **before** (let it be an ArrayList for example), that has the elements of a, b, c, d, e, f, g, ....
Here is what you do:

```
ArrayList<Integer> after;
while(before.size() > 1){
    after = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<(before.size()-1);i++){
        int joinedValue = joinValuesFunction(before.get(i),before.get(i+1));
        after.add(joinedValue);
    }
    before = after;
}
```

You can avoid creating new lists by reusing the **before** list if you would remove and replace the elements of **before** with the elements of after as soon as you'd calculate them. For example:

```
while(before.size() > 1){
    for(int i=0;i<(before.size()-1);i++){
        int joinedValue = joinValuesFunction(before.get(i),before.get(i+1));
        before.remove(i); //Remove the element at position i
        before.add(i,joinedValue); //Add the joined value at position i. This will shift all elements of this ArrayList (from i to before.getSize()-1) to the right by one position.
    }
    before.remove(before.size()-1); //Removes the last element
}
```

Not sure which is faster though. Try to time both approaches and let us know.

Hope this helps.